# Can't figure out what i'm doing wrong with arrays -- warning i am new and learning

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>

int playerscores() //function asking how many points each player has
{
//  int p; //player number we are on
//  p++; //since player number starts on zero, add one to print player #1
    int n;
    n++;
    printf("how many points does player %d have?\n", n);
    scanf("%d", &n); //asking how many points and writing to variable n
    return n; //output variable n
}

int main()
{
    int n; //numberof players
    int scoret = 0; //score total
    printf("How many players are on your team?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n); //asking number of players
    int score[n];  // integer array to store player scores
    int a = 1; //starting number for loop, indicating to start on player 1
    while(a <=  n)
    {
        score[a-1] = playerscores(); //calling function and define array at position b as equal to function output
        printf("%d", score[a-1]); //me trying to trouble shoot
        a++; //next player
        scoret = scoret + score[a-1]; //adding up scores thus far
        printf("%d", scoret); //more of me attempting to trouble shoot
    }

    return scoret; //final score

}
```

I'm just getting into coding and trying to learn on my own, using codesdope.com. I am on the array section now. I like to write a little bit of custom code just to familiarize my self but i can't seem to figure this one out. Every time i run this, the output is some crazy big number, looks like it is the address rather than the value. I don't think i ever call the address at any point but i'm not sure what else i could be doing wrong. Thanks for your alls help!

Comment: You never initialized `b`.

Comment: You also never update `b`, so you're writing to the same array element every time.

Comment: There's no need for `b`, you can use `score[a-1]`

Comment: i removed b, and used a-1 like you said, but its still returning what looks like an address rather than the actual value.

Comment: `int p` is local to that function, is never initialized, and even if it was, falls out of scope each time that function exits. You should use `n` instead of `p`.

Comment: I'm not sure i quite understand. I went and removed p from the 'playerscore' function and removed the required input as now i see it is redundant, but its still outputting that long number.

Comment: You cannot use any input function correct (or any function that manipulates data critical to the continued valid operation of your code) without ***checking the return***. You may want to ditch your website and see [**The Definitive C Book Guide and List**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There biggest issues I see here:

1) As already mentioned the local variable p / n. As you make the declaration within the function body, this variable will be initialized every time you call that function, so it will not remember the current value. Additionally, you don't initialize the variable with a value, means it could be 0 when you call it, but also any other number.

2) The issue with the big number comes from the order of the commands you execute. When you execute your loop the first time, you store your result in `score[a-1]` which is  `score[0]`. Now your issue: you increase a by 1, and afterwards you add the score to your global score, which results in `scoret = scoret + score[1]`. As you didn't initialize or assign something to `score[1]`, you don'T know what'S inside, it may be `0`, but maybe also `13567325`.

One possibility to implement your functionality would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int playerscores(int n) //function asking how many points each player has
{
    int p = 0; //variable storing the points
    printf("how many points does player %d have?\n", n+1);
    scanf("%d", &p); //asking how many points and writing to variable p
    return p; //return p for the points
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0; //number of players
    int scoret = 0; //score total
    printf("How many players are on your team?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n); //asking number of players
    int score[n];  // integer array to store player scores

    // using a for loop -> don't need to worry about incrementing the index
    for (int a = 0; a < n; a++)
    {
        score[a] = playerscores(a); //calling function and define array at position a
        scoret += score[a]; //adding up scores thus far
    }

    printf("Total score: %d\n", scoret);

    return scoret; //final score
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This explains all the garbage haha, and really helped me understand!

Answer (score 0):

In

```
printf("%d", score[a-1]); //me trying to trouble shoot
a++; //next player
scoret = scoret + score[a-1]; //adding up scores thus far
```

you need to change the order of the lines

```
printf("%d", score[a-1]); //me trying to trouble shoot
scoret = scoret + score[a-1]; //adding up scores thus far
a++; //next player
```

or change the index

```
printf("%d", score[a-1]); //me trying to trouble shoot
a++; //next player
scoret = scoret + score[a-2]; //adding up scores thus far
```

Side note: if you don't need the side effect of post-fix operator++ (as in `a++`), then use the prefix variant (as in `++a`).

Answer (score 0):

I've just changed the ordering of `scoret` variable, hope this code will work the way you want it to.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int playerscores(int curr_player) //function asking how many points each player has
{
    int p = curr_player; //player number we are on
    int curr_score = 0; 
   // p++; //since player number starts on zero, add one to print player #1
    printf("how many points does player %d have?\n", p);
    scanf("%d", &curr_score); //asking how many points and writing to variable n
    return curr_score; //output variable n
}

int main()
{
    int n; //numberof players
    int scoret = 0; //score total
    printf("How many players are on your team?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n); //asking number of players
    int score[n];  // integer array to store player scores
    int a = 1; //starting number for loop, indicating to start on player 1
    while(a <=  n)
    {
        score[a] = playerscores(a); //calling function and define array at position b as equal to function output
        printf("%d", score[a]); //me trying to trouble shoot
        scoret += score[a]; //adding up scores thus far
        a++;
    }
    printf(" %d", scoret); //more of me attempting to trouble shoot
    return scoret; //final score
}
```

In the lines:

```
a++; //next player
scoret = scoret + score[a-1]; //adding up scores thus far
```

you were incrementing `a` to the next position in the memory before adding it to `scoret` and the next position seems to hold garbage values that was showing up every time in your

```
printf("%d", score[a-1]); //me trying to trouble shoot
```

line